# Acessar através de JavaScript/Jquery um elemento que veio por AJAX depois do LOAD do DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, dom

Estou desenvolvendo uma WEB APP com AngularJS, existe um elemento que está vindo para o DOM depois do seu carregamento (load), estou tentando escrever um evento :

```
$('elemento').click()
```

Porém quando terminar de renderizar a página o elemento ainda não existe pois ele está vindo por ajax através do Angular, e devido a isso o evento não está sendo associado a ele.

Como associar Eventos ou Capturar elementos, que entram no DOM depois do seu LOAD?

Comment: Via Angular, utilize  `$compile(elemento)` para que ele seja interpretado.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o meu problema! Estava precisando fazer com que um elemento que veio de forma dinâmica através de AJAX ser reconhecido por meio de JavaScript/JQuery e poder escrever um Evento para este elemento.

Conseguir fazer isso através do método .live() do JQuery, segue o exemplo:

```
$('elemento').live('click',function(){})
```

Comment: Você usa o Jquery 1.4? Seria bom ter colocado na pergunta.

Comment: O ideal é usar o `.on()` da seguinte forma: `$('elementoPai').on('click', 'elemento', function(){});`, visto que o live foi depreciado na versão 1.7 e removido na versão 1.9. Caso futuramente precise atualizar o jQuery, seu código não funcionará mais.